# Find elements by xpath for selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm following this tutorial https://towardsdatascience.com/data-science-skills-web-scraping-javascript-using-python-97a29738353f

and when it comes to the part where we must copy XML path(around mid page) she writes something like this

```
# updated Nov 2019:
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class=' co-product-list__main-cntr']//*[@class=' co-item ']//*[@class='co-product']//*[@class='co-item__title-container']//*[@class='co-product__title']")
print('Number of results', len(results))
```

whereas when I do copy XML path i get something like this

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/span/div[1]/div/div[2]/li/ul/div/div/div[2]/div[4]
```

how to I get the part inside the parenthesis in the result variable ?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is how to get the XPath of an element?

Comment: Hi, are you getting the result as expected?

Comment: You are getting full XPath. If you use Chrome, you can copy XPath not pull XPath. However, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @JenilDave No I don't get the expected result. Yoshi when I copy the xpath I get something that doesn't look like what is written in the tutorial, so I was wondering how to get what is written(apparently copy xpath doesn't give the same solution. Osadhi I'm not sure what you mean by it doesn't matter, but this line of xml doesn't work for me